Error usando el metodo .compute() de Scikit-Fuzzy Python
estoy trabajando en un sistema que utiliza logica difusa, la idea es evaluar el nivel de conocimiento de los alumnos en base a algunos parametros, hasta alli no he tenido inconvenientes pero al momento de evaluar mi controlador da errores al ingresar ciertos valores en las entradas, no se si sea por los rangos de las entradas o inclusive algun problema en la definicion de mis reglas.
Les comparto un ejemplo:
    #Valores linguisticos de las entradas
f1['Deficiente'] = fuzz.trimf(f1.universe, [0, 3, 5])
f1['Estable'] = fuzz.trimf(f1.universe, [5, 7, 8])
f1['Creciente'] = fuzz.trimf(f1.universe, [8, 9, 10])

f2['Debajodelamedia'] = fuzz.trimf(f2.universe, [0, 3, 5])
f2['Alrededordelamedia'] = fuzz.trimf(f2.universe,  [6, 7, 8])
f2['Arribadelamedia'] = fuzz.trimf(f2.universe, [8, 9, 10])

f3['NoSatisfactorio'] = fuzz.trimf(f3.universe, [0, 4, 6])
f3['Satisfactorio'] = fuzz.trimf(f3.universe, [6, 7, 8])
f3['MuySatisfactorio'] = fuzz.trimf(f3.universe, [8, 9, 10])

    #Valores linguisticos de las salidas

Nc['Bajorendimiento'] = fuzz.trimf(Nc.universe, [0, 4, 6])
Nc['Mediorendimiento'] = fuzz.trimf(Nc.universe, [6, 7, 8])
Nc['Altorendimiento'] = fuzz.trimf(Nc.universe, [8, 9, 10])

Aqui algunas de las reglas ya que son bastantes para poner aqui:
    r1 = control.Rule(f1['Deficiente'] & f2['Arribadelamedia'] & f3['MuySatisfactorio'], Nc['Altorendimiento'])
r2 = control.Rule(f1['Deficiente'] & f2['Arribadelamedia'] & f3['Satisfactorio'], Nc['Mediorendimiento'])
r3 = control.Rule(f1['Deficiente'] & f2['Arribadelamedia'] & f3['NoSatisfactorio'], Nc['Bajorendimiento'])

    #Controlador
educacionController = control.ControlSystem([r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,r13,r14,r15,r16,r17,r18,r19,r20, r21,r22,r23,r24,r25,r26,r27])
educacionSimulator = control.ControlSystemSimulation(educacionController, flush_after_run= 21 * 21 + 1)

    educacionSimulator.input['f1'] = 9
educacionSimulator.input['f2'] = 7
educacionSimulator.input['f3'] = 6

    # Calcula la salida difusa
educacionSimulator.compute()

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/skfuzzy/control/controlsystem.py in defuzz(self)
    585             try:
--> 586                 return defuzz(ups_universe, output_mf,
    587                               self.var.defuzzify_method)

3 frames
AssertionError: Total area is zero in defuzzification!

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/skfuzzy/control/controlsystem.py in defuzz(self)
    587                               self.var.defuzzify_method)
    588             except AssertionError:
--> 589                 raise ValueError("Crisp output cannot be calculated, likely "
    590                                  "because the system is too sparse. Check to "
    591                                  "make sure this set of input values will "

ValueError: Crisp output cannot be calculated, likely because the system is too sparse. Check to make sure this set of input values will activate at least one connected Term in each Antecedent via the current set of Rules.

Lo curioso es que en los valores de membresia o pertenencia me indica que si existen valores:
=====Progresion de notas===== 
Deficiente 0.0 
Estable 0.0 
Creciente 1.0
=====Aprobacion de notas===== 
Deficiente 0.0 
Estable 1.0 
Creciente 0.0
=====Notas final del curso===== 
Deficiente 0.0 
Estable 0.5 
Creciente 0.0

He probado algunos valores algunos funcionan y otros no obviamente la idea es que funcione con cualquier valor

El error se devia al rango de los antecedentes, si estan armando un sistema logico difuso asegurense de tener bien definidos los rangos de valores para las funciones de pertenencia, pronto estare agregando aqui el repositorio del sistema para quien guste consultar.
Nota : lamentablemente algunos modulos de la libreria scikit-fuzzy no estan actualizados a la fecha que escribo esto.
Repositorio:
https://github.com/AldoGranillo/Sistema-Logico-Difuso

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
